# Unable to run docker commands

Tags: unix, tcp, docker

I am running docker using the command

```
sudo docker -H 0.0.0.0:2375 -d &
```

I am then using teh dockerjava client to create images and run containers in the following way

```
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("http://localhost:2375").build();
            l
                CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(image_name)
                        .exec();
                dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
```

This works fine and the docker logs look fine too. But when I try to use any of the docker commands including `docker ps, docker images, docker info`, all of them fail with the following error

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Using sud also does not solve the problem. I am running docker on unix. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using boot2docker? In that case you need to do `$(boot2docker shellinit)` to set the DOCKER_HOST. Otherwise, just do `export DOCKER_HOST==tcp://<your-ip>:2376`, `export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=<path-to-cernts>` and `export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1`.

Comment: I am on unix, tahnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using sudo also does not solve the problem. I am running docker on unix. Any thoughts?

You have started up Docker listening on a TCP socket.  This means that when the `docker` client attempts to connect to the default Unix-domain socket, there's nothing there.  The error message is pretty clear about that:

```
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
```

You need to tell the `docker` client where to connect, just like you have to provide that information to the `DockerClientBuilder` class in your code.  You can do this (a) using the `-H` option to the client or (b) using the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable.

For example:

```
$ docker -H http://localhost:2375 ps
$ docker -H http://localhost:2375 pull alpine
```

Or:

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=http://localhost:2375
$ docker ps
$ docker pull alpine
```